# How to find a variable length string, using RegEx

Tags: regex, bulk-rename-utility

I am trying to use a bulk rename tool to strip off an ID from migrated documents. I am struggling with the Regex.

Here is an example of some of the documents.

```
KIN-CHV-SAL-MAP-001 (ID 594).pptx
KIN-CHV-P18005-REP-001 R1 (ID 04).pdf
```

I basically need the Regex to find any instances of "(ID" then delete those characters and any other after it up the the ")". So the documents would look like this:

```
KIN-CHV-SAL-MAP-001.pptx
KIN-CHV-P18005-REP-001 R1.pdf
```

The amount of characters in-between the brackets varies and some documents do not have an ID.
This is where i intend to use the RegEx.

[image: Rename tool]

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
MATCH:   ^(.*?)\s*\(ID \d+\)
REPLACE: \1
Include Ext. must be UNCHECKED
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - one or more whitespace chars
- `\(ID \d+\)` - `ID`, space, 1+ digits and `)`.

The replacement is the contents of Group 1 (the string from the beginning till the `(ID <<digits>>)`.

See screenshot:

[image]